# replacing or managing json data from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a page that makes an ajax request and gets data back in json format.

I needed to sort this data before adding it to the DOM, so it is put into an object with the following code

```
function(data) {
  var birthDates = {};
  var uids = {};
  $.each(data.users, function() {

    if (!uids[this.uid]) {
      uids[this.uid] = [];
      uids[this.uid].push(this);
    }
    if (!birthDates[this.birthDate])
      birthDates[this.birthDate] = [];
    birthDates[this.birthDate].push(this);
  });
  for (var d in birthDates) {
    var date = d;
    $('div#holdDates').append('<ul class="dayList" id="' + date + '"><li class="date" >' + date + '</li></ul>');
    $.each(birthDates[date], function() {
      $('ul#' + date).append('<li class="show" id="' + this.uid + '">' + this.name + '</li>');
    });
  }

  $('li.show').click(function() {
        var getuid = $(this).attr('id');
        $showArr = uids[getuid];
        // now I can get the extended data about the user
```

this all works great when the page is loaded for the first time, however I'm running into two problems, both as a result of making a second ajax request
1) if i make the same ajax request (giving the same variables, so the same data comes back again), then the data gets added to the newly created objects (uids, and birthDates) twice, and I can't figure out how to keep that as unique
2) sometimes (and i haven't been able to debug to figure out why) i don't get any of the extended user data from uids object. (the stuff I do after the li click

Any ideas? Am i doing this efficiently?
I find it strange that you can't empty an object that you've created, but apparently everything I'm reading says that you can't.

### Addition

well, after posting this, the next thing I was doing was building a dynamic tag cloud which is dependent on the returned json. 
so, now I run into the same problem again. I need to tag-cloud to be new after each request. I really hope there is a way to get rid of 'legacy' data in javascript.

Thanks, 
Pete

Comment: where are you setting the id of the li.show?

Comment: Also is your user data in the array twice, or is the entire new list getting added to $('div#holdDates') at the end?

Comment: sorry, i didn't see these comments earlier bendewey.
1st - the li of show is being set in <pre> $('ul#'+date).append(</pre>
there is a bunch of stuff in there, but I didn't want to clutter the question.
2) the list should not be 'added' to holdDates, as I'm trying to get rid of the previous 'list'

Answer (score 1):

Everything declared with the var keyword inside of your function(data) will be created anew each time the function is called.

What's the symptom of your problem? Have you actually looked at the value of the uids variable in firebug and seen that items are being duplicated, or do you just see your dates/names getting doubled up on the page?

My suspicion is that this is a result of not clearing the DOM elements that you are calling .append() on before you display your results.

Try adding to the beginning of the function:

```
$('div#holdDates').empty();
```

as well as to your date display loop:

```
$('ul#'+date).empty();
```

and for good measure, at the beginning of function:

```
$('li.show').unbind('click');
```